# Auto cropping and resizing images

Tags: chessboard.js

I'd like to write a python script that does the following manipulation for a bulk of images:

[chessboard manipulation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMN0x.jpg)

This example was achieved using CamScanner's auto-crop. I'd like to mimic it. What it does? It takes an image of a chessboard taken on mobile phone, and crops it to the dims of the chessboard, as well as resizing it to a view from the upper side.

I've tried opencv camera caliberation algorithm but that didn't work out quite well.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is vague!  You show only one image for an example and do not say clearly what needs to be done to it. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I found the output to the right of your input. Find the 4 corners of your chessboard by thresholding and morphology and corners or intersections of Hough lines. Then define the size of the output. Then get the homography between the two sets of points. Then do warpPerspective. Search Google. There have been a number of examples of that on this forum.

Comment: Related: https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/ and https://learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/ and http://www.raspberryturk.com/details/vision/camera_calibration.html

Comment: Thank you! cv2.findChessboardCorners seams like a good starting point.

Comment: another one that works well is PIL  ImageTransform.QuadTransform.